# Quiero guardar la data de un formulario en variables javascript y luego llenar otro formulario con esas variables

Tags: javascript, html

Script:

```
var texto = "";
function getData() {
    "use strict";
    texto = document.getElementById("texto").value;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="capturador.js"></script>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="form3.html" onsubmit="getData()">
            <label id="label1"></label><br>
            <input id="texto" type="text" name="texto" >
            <br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Y esto:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="capturador.js"></script>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="" onsubmit="getData()">
          <label id="label1"></label><br>
          <input id="texto1" type="text" name="texto1" >
          <br>
          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Mostrar Data">
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Disculpen la ignorancia apenas llevo 2 días viendo videos y trabajando con javascript.

Comment: Veamos, ¿quieres obtener la información guardada una variable en javascript desde otra página? o ¿quieres obtener la información guardada en la misma página?

Comment: Andres Morales,tengo un archivo .js donde capturo la data del primer formulario en variables,pero no encuentro la forma de ese valor qe capturo asignarselo al input de otro formulario diferente,y si es practicamente eso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías optar en utilizar sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

Para recuperar el valor:

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

y para borrar:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('key') o sessionStorage.clear()
```

Comment: bueno leere para saber utilizarlo un tanto mejor,ya que como dije soy nuevo en esto pero desde que pruebe aviso que tal

Comment: Creo que esta es tu mejor opción. Si los datos no son críticos y son manejables en tamaño podrías también enviarlos en la queryString.

Comment: solo quiero mandar los datos de un login a un iframe para que tome esos datos y logue apartir de esos datos la vdd,pero debo hacer con javascript y con javascript nose ni psar datos entre formularios,por eso quiero aprender lo basico para luego intentarlo

Comment: me funcionaron la sessionStorage muchas gracias chicos

Answer (score 0):

Otra manera es utilizando QueryString (como menciona @Kiko_L), donde obtienes el valor del input desde la URL, te dejo un ejemplo:

HTML 1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
        <form action="get.html">
            <input type="text" name="serialNumber" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML 2:

```
<body>
<div id="write">
</div>
<script>
    function getParamValuesByName (querystring) {
        var qstring = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < qstring.length; i++) {
            var urlparam = qstring[i].split('=');
            if (urlparam[0] == querystring) {
            return urlparam[1];
            }
        }
    }
    var uid = getParamValuesByName('serialNumber');

    document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = uid;
</script>
```

En el HTML 2 asigno el valor del input a una variable (uid) al div "write".

Espero sea de ayuda éste ejemplo.